# Get minimum value row based on column values

Tags: mysql

I have below table which stores my product prices and special prices data for my products. I want to get the least price product from below data.

```
+------+-------+---------------+-------------------+-----------------+
|  id  | price | special_price | special_from_date | special_to_date |
+------+-------+---------------+-------------------+-----------------+
| 2647 |   299 |           251 | NULL              | NULL            |
| 2648 |   299 |            85 | 2017-12-29        | 2018-02-28      |
| 2649 |   299 |          NULL | 2017-12-29        | 2018-02-28      |
| 2650 |   299 |            55 | 2017-12-29        | 2018-01-01      |
| 2651 |   299 |           179 | 2017-12-29        | NULL            |
+------+-------+---------------+-------------------+-----------------+
```

The tricky part here is that I want to check below conditions.

1. Check `price` column for minimum product price.
2. Skip `special_price` if `NULL`
3. Skip `special_price`
   if `special_from_date` and `special_to_date` is `NULL` or current
   date does not fall between range
4. Check `special_price` column if
   `special_from_date` is not `NULL` and `special_from_date` is less than current date and `special_to_date` is either
   `NULL` or greater than current date.

The output will be like below.

```
+------+-------+---------------+-------------------+-----------------+
|  id  | price | special_price | special_from_date | special_to_date |
+------+-------+---------------+-------------------+-----------------+
| 2648 |   299 |            85 | 2017-12-29        | 2018-02-28      |
+------+-------+---------------+-------------------+-----------------+
```

Here is my table schema.

```
+------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                  | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id                     | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| price                  | decimal(12,4)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| special_price          | decimal(12,4)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| special_from_date      | date                | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| special_to_date        | date                | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Please add table schema.

Comment: `2018-02-29` is not a valid date

Comment: I don't see what's so tricky about this query. You'll need `WHERE`, `GROUP BY` (that's not clear from your question. Where's the product id in your table?), and `MIN()`. After completing a sql tutorial you should be able to write the appropriate query. Please have a try and post the result. It would probably clear up the question as well.

Comment: @tombom, Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try from my side and will add query to the question. PS: this is just the demo table, my original table contains a lot more data but I have only used the columns which are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the current price as follows:

Use `special_price` when:

1. `special_price` is not NULL
2. `special_from_date` is not NULL
3. `special_from_date` is not greater than today
4. One of the following applies (OR condition)

   - `special_to_date` is NULL (open)
   - `special_to_date` is not less than current date

Otherwise use (default) `price`.

Since a comparison will "fail" if one side is NULL, (2) is redundant with (3)  and can be skipped.

To avoid an OR-condition, (4) can be expressed as `coalesce(special_to_date, curdate()) >= curdate()`.

```sql
select p.*,
  case
    when  special_price is not null -- 1
      and curdate() >= special_from_date -- 2 and 3
      and curdate() <= coalesce(special_to_date, curdate()) -- 4
    then special_price
    else price
  end as current_price
from prices p
order by current_price asc
limit 1
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/ETEU48971

Note that it's not quite clear, if you want to include `special_from_date` and `special_to_date` into the range. In this case they are included. If you want to exclude them, you can use:

```
      and curdate() > special_from_date
      and curdate() < coalesce(special_to_date, curdate() + interval 1 day)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. that worked for me. I was not aware of `coalesce`

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that if CURDATE() doesn't fit any range of dates you'll get no rows.

> ```
> select   id, 
>          min(price) price, 
>          special_price, 
>          special_from_date,
>          special_to_date
> from     prices
> where    special_price is not null
> and      special_from_date is not null
> and      special_to_date is not null
> and      (curdate() >= special_from_date
>           and
>           curdate() <= special_to_date)
> group by id
> ```
>
> ```
>   id |    price | special_price | special_from_date | special_to_date
> ---: | -------: | ------------: | :---------------- | :--------------
> 2648 | 299.0000 |       85.0000 | 2017-12-29        | 2018-02-28
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=ea837d281d242d41eef0c632e8090e8f)*

Comment: Thank you for this answer, but it is not working if special_to_date is null

Comment: I've removed rows where special_to_date is null or special_from_date is null

Comment: I mean if `special_to_date` for `2648` column is `NULL`, it should fetch the same row and not skip it. Because `NULL` value for `special_to_date` means there is no expiry date for special price.

Comment: then you'll get two rows, 2648, 2651

Comment: You are grouping by the primary key. That doesn't make sence in a single table select statement.